# How can you pass the same argument twice in a python sqlite3 nested query?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to pass data into a nested sqlite3 query in python and I get the following error

> Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 1 supplied.

```sql
x = uid
sql_query1 = """SELECT title FROM movies WHERE addedBy != ? AND mid NOT IN (SELECT mid FROM ratings WHERE uid = ?);"""
data = (uid, x)
cursor.execute(sql_query1, [data])
movies = cursor.fetchall()
```

I'm guessing the problem might be that `x = uid`, I have also tried `data = (uid, uid)` and `cursor.execute(sql_query1, [uid])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply as many parameters as you have question marks.

```
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT title 
    FROM movies
    WHERE addedBy != ?
        AND mid NOT IN (SELECT mid FROM ratings WHERE uid = ?);
""", [uid, uid])

movies = cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 2):

Parameters can be explicitly numbered, and the same value used for all instances of a given number:

```
sql_query1 = """
  SELECT title
  FROM movies
  WHERE addedBy != ?1 AND mid NOT IN (SELECT mid FROM ratings WHERE uid = ?1);"""
cursor.execute(sql_query1, (uid,))
```